# DNS configuration in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, dns, nameserver

I am designing a private LAN in Linux,

I have a dns server locally which had an ip address 192.168.0.20 ,

I had installed BIND in this server and configured both FORWARD AND REVERSE look-up in /var/named.conf for a domain name example.com something as follows.

```
zone "example.com" {
type master;
file "/var/named/example.com.zone";
allow-update { none; };
};


zone "20.0.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" {
type master;
file "/var/named/example.com.zone.rr";
allow-update { none; };
};
```

Additionally I had created following two files and added the NS, CNAME, MX, A, SOA records appropriately.

```
/var/named/example.com.zone
/var/named/example.com.zone.rr
```

MY Issue is - I had added the above dns-server 192.168.0.20 as dns1 in another machine 192.168.0.25, But I cannot ping to example.com from 192.168.0.25 , what is the issue for that, or I missed some thing to do ?

Answer (score 1):

go to /etc/bind/db

1. create a forward zone with your name "**db.ramkee.local**" . you can choose any name instead of ramkee. am just taking it as an example.

**vi db.ramkee.local**

[image]

2 . Then create reverse zone **rev.22.168.192.in-addr.arpa**

**vim rev.22.168.192.in-addr.arpa**

[image]

3 .Then create a master zone

**vim named.conf.local**

[image]

4 .reload and restart the bind9 service

**/etc/init.d/bind9 reload**

**/etc/init.d/bind9 restart**

it must dont show any errors. if you got any errors you must have look at your 3 files( especially pullstops(.), comma(,) )

5 . set resolv.conf as DNS server IP

**vim /etc/resolv.conf**

**nameserver 192.168.22.22**

6 .then try to nslookup with yourself (IP and FQDN)

**nslookup 192.168.22.22**

**nslookup server.ramkee.local**

then it will show you the details of that FQDN and IP

Still if you got  any errors please revert here

this setup will work on ubuntu 12.04. and i have mention only for 192.168.22.X range. if you want another range let me know

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot ping to hostname from other machine

Comment: ok.. check your firewall status by using this command "service ufw cstatus"  and try to ping google.com from your machine. can you provide the details of your /etc/network/interface.

Comment: see that your ip public or hostonly

Comment: Thanks..ip is NOT public, here is the information in /etc/networks -  defaults 0.0.0.0, loopback 127.0.0.0, link.local 169.254.0.0, Firwall status NAT, Filter and Mangle tables are empty, no blocking for both systems, /etc/resolv.conf contains 192.168.0.20(the server which configured bind)

Answer (score 0):

You set the DNS to example.**name** and you search example.**com**. A bit different, huh?

You can find explanation about named.conf [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-bind-namedconf.html)

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points in your answer and use the link as reference. Thanks.

Comment: Main point is the first sentence. And the link is only a reference. Without configuration file _/var/named/example.com.zone_ nothing more can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your response @LHristov, But unfortunately there is nothing valuable from your link, for my question, so I think,  it would be nice if you erase that answer..

Answer (score 0):

Reverse-mapping zones can be a bit tricky.  You really need to match up with the address space you are using, in this case, [RFC1918](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt) private address space 192.168.0.0/16.  This means you should use 168.192.in-addr.arpa for your reverse-mappng zone.

I.e.,

```
zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
   type master;
   file "/var/named/example.com.zone.rr";
   allow-update { none; };
};
```

And in your file for this one, you'll have entries like:

```
20.0       IN PTR  dns-server.example.com.
25.0       IN PTR  dns2-server.example.com.
```

Note the trailing period on the names and the backwards octets for the IP addresses.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think we cannot add two decimal points in PTR, only only last decimal point is allowed.. But my final issue is not yet solved, I need to ping example.com from the system 192.168.0.25, its dns1 is 192.168.0.20 (in this system we configured the bind, all ns, mx, cname are working correctly in this server)..any idea of this issue?

Comment: If you try it exactly how I have it, it will work.  The "dots" (.) are just domain separators and you have to have a "." at the end of a name to fully-qualify it in these files.  Anything without a trailing-dot will be processed as a relative name, and in this case, has ".168.192.in-addr.arpa." appended to it.  So "20.0" will become "20.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa." which is what you need.

Comment: If you cannot ping "example.com", then you have not created an A record for the empty (or @) domain in your `example.com.zone` file.  Make sure you have
`@        IN A  1.2.3.4`
(with the right IP address of course)

Comment: Thanks That seems something informative, but I am not able to ping it, all records are working correctly in the dns server itself 192.168.0.20 , dig and nslookup seems NOERROR

Comment: Then you have a connectivity problem if DNS is resolving.

Comment: ping to ip address in working fine, but ping to host name is not working, could you please suggest